# @emotion/react build error when building using Azure

Tags: reactjs, azure-devops, emotion

I am trying to build a Material-UI v5 app which has @emotion/react as a dependency. "npm run build" works locally, but when I try to build it through Azure pipelines, it breaks. Please advice.

It asks me to install "isolated-hoist-non-react-statistics...."

[image]

Comment: Have you tried install the hoist-non-react-methods by run "npm i hoist-non-react-statics"?

Comment: Yes, I did. Still doesnt work.